# audio file is not appended to the form data in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, forms, form-data, mediarecorder

After recording the sound with the microphone, I want to send the recorded voice to the API, but unfortunately the form data(it's been logged in line 37) is an empty object and I cannot send the recorded file to the API.

I've used mic-recorder-to-mp3 for recording from the microphone and my problem is inside the stop function, Is using new File() and new FormData() correct for sending the recorded audio file to the server?

```
import React from "react";
import "./App.css";
import MicRecorder from "mic-recorder-to-mp3";
import axios from "axios";

const Mp3Recorder = new MicRecorder({ bitRate: 128 });

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      isRecording: false,
      blobURL: "",
      isBlocked: false,
    };
  }

  start = () => {
    if (this.state.isBlocked) {
      console.log("Permission Denied");
    } else {
      Mp3Recorder.start()
        .then(() => {
          this.setState({ isRecording: true });
        })
        .catch((e) => console.error(e));
    }
  };

  stop = () => {
    Mp3Recorder.stop()
      .getMp3()
      .then(([buffer, blob]) => {
        const convertedfile = new File([blob], "fileInput.mp3");
        const formData = new FormData();
        formData.append("file", convertedfile);
        console.log(formData,"Form Data"); 

        axios
          .post(
            "https://192.168.33.18:3002/api/users/895630b7-2854-4f96-9d46-e8e80529f725/faqArchives/file",
            {
              file: formData,
            }
          )
          .then(function (response) {
            console.log(response);
          })
          .catch(function (error) {
            console.log(error);
          });

        const blobURL = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
        this.setState({ blobURL, isRecording: false });
      })
      .catch((e) => console.log(e));
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    navigator.getUserMedia(
      { audio: true },
      () => {
        console.log("Permission Granted");
        this.setState({ isBlocked: false });
      },
      () => {
        console.log("Permission Denied");
        this.setState({ isBlocked: true });
      }
    );
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <header className="App-header">
          <button onClick={this.start} disabled={this.state.isRecording}>
            Record
          </button>
          <button onClick={this.stop} disabled={!this.state.isRecording}>
            Stop
          </button>
          <audio src={this.state.blobURL} controls="controls" />
        </header>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Having the same issue, did you manage to solve it?